# How to reference a timerPicker in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, emulation, release

When this program runs on the emulator it works, however, when I run it on my phone the **timePicker** is referenced as null.

An emulator running API 26 can run it fine, however, at API 28 it does not work. So I think It might be something with API 28 (which also is what my phone runs)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val picker = findViewById<TimePicker>(R.id.timePicker)

        val t = picker == null // Is true on phone and is false on emulator

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        //picker.setIs24HourView(true)

        val activity = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.activityName)
        val mCallApiButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submit)
        mCallApiButton?.setOnClickListener{
            val time = GetTime(picker)

            PostActivity(time, activity.text.toString()) // Function that does other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I need to reference the **timePicker** so that I can set it to 24H.

Here is a look at the layout file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:timePickerMode="clock"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/activityName"
                android:singleLine="true" android:hint="Activity" android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAlignment="center" android:autofillHints="Activity"/>
        <Button
                android:text="Submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/submit"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot of the emulator: (Which is how it should look)
[image]

Screenshot of the phone:
[image]

Comment: Please check your device setting is same as that of emulator

Comment: try to clean-rebuild your project and check again, it must be no difference in your case between phone and emulator

Comment: @Shalu T D do you mean the os version, or is it the actual settings in android?

Comment: @Dmitriy Pavlukhin this made no difference

Comment: What phone do you have? And is timepicker visible in activity layout?

Comment: @DmitriyPavlukhin I have a Huawei Mate 10 Pro and  the timePicker is visible in Design tab in Android Studio, however, on the phone, it is not shown as a clock but as a text field, and for some reason, a button is missing

Comment: @ShaluTD It seems you are right when I change the API level to match my phone (API 28 instead of 26) it breaks

Comment: I think you go the wrong way. First, you're not using Xamarin are you? Second, its allright with API 28 and TimePicker in my case on both emulator and phone. Maybe issue is in somewhere else

Comment: @DmitriyPavlukhin no I'm not using Xamarin. Are you sure you have the timepicker in the XML file from the beginning, because if I instantiate at button press it works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I use API 28 and not 27 and under. The answer can found here:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5159